# Views preferences in Files

Tags: permissions, files

I am new to ubuntu and I don't know how to get to the files permissions. It seems pretty straightforward in https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-views.html but I just have no idea how to select Select Files ▸ Preferences. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

To view/change permissions in Nautilus, the default file manager in Gnome and Unity, right click on the file and select properties:

> [image]

Then go to the Permissions tab and you can change who can read and write to a file

[image]

I think to change the owner you need to run nautilus as root - to do this (in Unity and sometimes Gnome), press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open 'Run a command' or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, and run:

```
gksu nautilus
```

enter you password and you can now change the owner:
[image]

eChanging permissions can also be done via commandline with thr [`chown`](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) and [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) commands.

---

If you want to change the view settings, use the icons to the top right, or the View menu in the top/menu bar:

[image]

To change File manager's preferences, go to 'Edit' > 'Preferences'
[image]